# Match Duplicates, Compare for Most Recent, Place Results

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to have the following:

1. Identify duplicates in `Sheet2!B:B`
2. In those columns with duplicates, compare dates in `Sheet2!A:A`
3. Identify most recent `Sheet2!A:A` date within that range of matching `Sheet2!B:B` duplicates
4. Deliver that most recent date to cell in `Sheet1!B:B` which corresponds to the repeating duplicate associated in `Sheet2!B:B`

Example:
to populate `Sheet1!A2`, formula needs to compare dates in `Sheet2!A5:A8` (based on detecting matches in `Sheet2!B5:B8`) to find most recent, which is 3/30/2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**google-spreadsheet formula**

Paste this formula in Sheet1, for example in cell `E1`:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A:B,
"select B, max(A) where not A is null group by B label B 'Name', max(A) 'Most Recent'")
```

[Sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11P6XDS0rmKP3aqlrfaOu-c0djlEOlBqeA_ijLugTKqM/edit#gid=0)

The result -- you get the report with on single formula.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Follow-up question for you: can I also include additional columns in the result? details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657582/trying-to-include-additional-columns-in-query-result-on-googlesheets