# Trying to include additional columns in QUERY result on GoogleSheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm using Google Sheets and using the following formula without any issue:

```
=QUERY(Sheet!A:D,"select A, max(B) where not B is null group by A label A 'Client', max(B) 'Most Recent'")
```

Obviously, this is returning columns A and B of the referenced data
However, I would like to also return the corresponding cells from column C.

sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJKiDNPUWMMUbLLb-UDA6iRA2PBnlMHDsEB9vELe0Rk/edit?usp=sharing

Using this example, what I would like to see is cell G2 populated with "Pizza" (i.e., from C3), and so on.

Am I using the right formula? What do I need to change?

Comment: Please don't tag `excel` with `googlesheets`.

Comment: I don't use google spreadsheets but I can look it up. Edit: lol the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) is cut off XD

Comment: Wow this is rather dense but guessing you just need to `select` C and D? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#overview

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not very SQL-like, because `max(B)` does not point to any particular row: it's just the maximum value of B among the selected rows. This value could be attained by several rows, making the choice of C, D ambiguous. I don't think that a single query can do this.

Here is an implementation with `unique` and several `query` commands.

In E2, enter `=unique(A:A)`  to get the list of unique client names.
In F2, enter

```
=query(A:D, "select B,C,D where A ='"&E2&"' order by B desc limit 1")
```

and drag this formula down. This selects all rows with the A value matching E2, and picks one with maximal B value.

You don't want to have a header row in the output of these queries so either add `label B '', C '', D ''` or just don't include the header row in the queried range.

---

#### Version with grouping by C,D

To also select C and D within a single query, expand the `select` clause

```
select A, max(B), C, D
```

which will then require including those in the `group by` clause:

```
group by A, C, D
```

The formula will be

```
=QUERY(A:D,"select A, max(B), C, D where not B is null group by A, C, D label A 'Client', max(B) 'Most Recent'")
```

This does mean that the only rows to be grouped together will be those where not only A but also C and D are equal.

Comment: That ALMOST worked. Problem is the result then includes all results where I need them filtered down to only the max(B) among repeated values in column A. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are the values in C and D also repeated when A is repeated? If yes, they will be grouped by this query. If no, what do you expect to select from C and D?

Comment: With the formula in my original post, duplicate values in A were queried for max(B) and delivered to output. I would like data from C and D that corresponds to the row with max(B) among each duplicate from A, still filtering out duplicate A rows that are not max(B)

Comment: This is still not well defined. What if there are two rows that achieve max(B), and they have different C entries?

Comment: I've added a link, in the original post above, to a spreadsheet with sample data.  What I'd like to have is a formula that will, for example, populate cell G2 with the text "Pizza"

Comment: I added a way to achieve what you want.

Comment: that starts to get at what I'm looking for, but when I drag the QUERY formula down, I get  the following #REF: "Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in F4." Is there different function I should be using altogether?

Comment: You don't want to have a header row in the output of these queries so either add ` label B '', C '', D ''` or just don't include the header row in the queried range.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did that finally worked.

In E1, enter `=unique(A:A)` to get the list of unique client names. In F2, enter

```
=query(A$2:D101, "select B,C,D where A ='"&F2&"' order by B desc limit 1")
```

and drag this formula down. This selects all rows with the A value matching E2, and picks one with maximal B value.

You don't want to have a header row in the output of these queries so just add desired text in header row.

Answer (score 1):

A possible one-formula solution:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A2:A),SORT(A2:C,2,0),{1,2,3},0)))`